# How to count the number of times each value of an attribute from one table, appears in another table? And if there is no appearance return zero

Tags: sql

If I have a CUSTOMER table with the attribute `customer_id` and an ORDER table
with the attributes `order_id` and `customer_id`.

How do I find the total number of orders submitted by each customer and if a customer has none, return zero.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM Customer c, Orders o
WHERE c.customer_id= o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

With the above, I am able to display the number of orders made by each customer, only if they made an order.

How do I also display count 0 for those customers who did not make any order?

Comment: (untested): you could use a LEFT JOIN to customers and that should list all customers, then you can display 0 whenever the count from the orders table is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join and count the rows in the "outer" table:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(o.customer_id)
FROM Customer c 
  LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.customer_id= o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and in the `COUNT()` place the `o.customer_id`

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(o.customer_id) AS OrderCount
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

Demo with sample data. Here Customer Id 2 and 4 doesn't have any data in the Orders table and it result zero in the ouput.

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (CustomerId INT);

INSERT INTO @Customer (CustomerId) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

DECLARE @Orders TABLE (CustomerId INT, OrderId INT);

INSERT INTO @Orders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4), (5, 1);

SELECT c.CustomerId, COUNT(o.CustomerId) AS OrderCount
FROM @Customer c
LEFT JOIN @Orders o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.CustomerId;
```

Output:

```
CustomerId  OrderCount
----------------------
1           2
2           0
3           2
4           0
5           1
```

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate the orders by customer ID and calculate the total count within an inner select. Make sure to left join this to your customers table so that you don't lose any of the customers that have not placed an order. Finally use a case statement to determine whether or not the return value for the number of orders for a customer is null meaning they have made no orders and in that case set the value to zero.

```sql
SELECT 
     c.customer_id, 
     CASE 
          WHEN o.num_orders IS NULL THEN 0
          ELSE o.num_orders
     END
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS num_orders 
     FROM Orders 
     GROUP BY customer_id
) AS o ON c.customer_id= o.customer_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the `IFNULL` function :
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp
hope it'll help!